# How to get the best matched object from a list in java from a list of objects?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a use case where I need to find the best match object from a list of given object based upon the object parameters

I have an object as Input in java

eg

```
 TestBestMatchModel("VERIFICATION", "6", "13", "15");
```

there is a list of input objects-

```
List<InputObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

which contains some objects like :-

```
TestBestMatchModel testBestMatchModel = new TestBestMatchModel("VERIFICATION",
        "6", "99999", "999999");
    TestBestMatchModel testBestMatchModel1 = new TestBestMatchModel("VERIFICATION",
        "6", "13", "999999");
    TestBestMatchModel testBestMatchModel2 = new TestBestMatchModel("VERIFICATION",
        "6", "2", "999999");
    TestBestMatchModel testBestMatchModel3 = new TestBestMatchModel("VERIFICATION",
        "6", "213", "9");
    TestBestMatchModel testBestMatchModel4 = new TestBestMatchModel("VERIFICATION",
        "6", "113", "999999");
    TestBestMatchModel testBestMatchModel5 = new TestBestMatchModel("VERIFICATION",
        "6", "13", "9");
```

So I am using stream method like

```
TestBestMatchModel result = test.stream()
            .filter(model -> model.getTransformation().equals("VERIFICATION")).max(
                Comparator.comparing(
                    model -> model.getLanguageID().equals("6")
                        && model.getVerticalID().equals("13")
                        && model.getDeviceID().equals("15")
                )).orElse(null);
```

and I am expecting the output will be - testBestMatchModel5

but instead of that I am getting "testBestMatchModel" value in the result

```
result is TestBestMatchModel{transformation='VERIFICATION', deviceID='999999', verticalID='99999', languageID='6'}
```

So what is the best way to get the "best matched" object from a list of objects.

Comment: Best match? There is only one matching object in your data. Why do you use `max()` over `Comparator.comparing`?

Comment: So please [edit] your question so that it matches the code you show us.

Comment: I get `TestBestMatchModel(transformation=VERIFICATION, languageID=6, verticalID=13, deviceID=9)` as result

Comment: check the [ideone demo](https://www.ideone.com/epT8Pv)

Comment: there is no element which is matched now as my input is TestBestMatchModel("VERIFICATION", "6", "13", "15"); so I am expecting the output should be testBestMatchModel5 which is TestBestMatchModel("VERIFICATION",
        "6", "13", "9"); but i am getting the output as TestBestMatchModel{transformation='VERIFICATION', deviceID='999999', verticalID='99999', languageID='6'}

Comment: I have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

You want to have "best match" but you don't define any "best match" logic only "match" logic.
You're just comparing a boolean value which says "all the fields are equal" or not.

```java
Comparator.comparing(
  model -> model.getLanguageID().equals("6")
         && model.getVerticalID().equals("13")
         && model.getDeviceID().equals("15")
)
```

Try to define `Comparable` for your class, and there define the best match logic as you desire:

```java
public class TestBestMatchModel implements Comparable<TestBestMatchModel> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(TestBestMatchModel other) {
       // Define best match logic
       // For example for every field equals +1 in score
       int score = 0;
       if (this.getLanguageID().equals(other.getLanguageID())
         score++;
       if (this.getVerticalID().equals(other.getVerticalID())
         score++;
       if (this.getDeviceID().equals(other.getDeviceID())
         score++;

       return score;
    }
}
```

And then you can just use it:

```java
TestBestMatchModel searchFor =  TestBestMatchModel("VERIFICATION", "6", "13", "15");
TestBestMatchModel result = test.stream()
            .filter(model -> model.getTransformation().equals("VERIFICATION"))
            .max(Comparator.comparing(m -> searchFor.compareTo(m)))
            .orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have misinterpreted the code that you have written. First Understand How max function actually. It will sort your object on the basis of keys passed to it and then takes the max out of it. In your case all object in the list with return false to max function. Now since every key is same in max function sorting will not take any effect (every key will be same (FIFO will work in that case.)). Before complex object try some basic program of max and min function [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/java8/stream-max-min-examples/).

```
model -> model.getLanguageID().equals("6")
                    && model.getVerticalID().equals("13")
                    && model.getDeviceID().equals("15")
```

**Since all keys have same values in side max function it resolve using First come first serve. So It is not about the "testBestMatchModel",
If you just change insertion order in list it will give different result with same code: Check my comment at follwing lines.

    list.add(testBestMatchModel1); // I put it before the testBestMatchModel;
    list.add(testBestMatchModel); //I inserted this to second position**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

TestBestMatchModel testBestMatchModel1 = new 
TestBestMatchModel("VERIFICATION",
    "6", "13", "999999");
TestBestMatchModel testBestMatchModel = new TestBestMatchModel("VERIFICATION",
    "6", "99999", "999999");
TestBestMatchModel testBestMatchModel2 = new 
TestBestMatchModel("VERIFICATION",
    "6", "2", "999999");
TestBestMatchModel testBestMatchModel3 = new 
TestBestMatchModel("VERIFICATION",
    "6", "213", "9");
TestBestMatchModel testBestMatchModel4 = new 
TestBestMatchModel("VERIFICATION",
    "6", "113", "999999");
TestBestMatchModel testBestMatchModel5 = new 
TestBestMatchModel("VERIFICATION",
    "6", "13", "9");
List<TestBestMatchModel> list= new ArrayList<>();
list.add(testBestMatchModel1); // I put it before the testBestMatchModel;
list.add(testBestMatchModel); //I inserted this to second position
list.add(testBestMatchModel2);
list.add(testBestMatchModel3);
list.add(testBestMatchModel4);
list.add(testBestMatchModel5);

TestBestMatchModel test = new TestBestMatchModel("VERIFICATION", "6", "13", "15");
TestBestMatchModel result = list.stream()
    .filter(model -> model.getTransformation().equals("VERIFICATION"))
    .max(Comparator.comparing(
            model -> model.getX().equals("6")
                && model.getY().equals("13")
                && model.getZ().equals("15")
        ))
    .orElse(null);
System.out.println(result);

}
}

class TestBestMatchModel {

private String transformation;
private String x;
private String y;
private String z;

public TestBestMatchModel(String transformation, String x, String y, String z) 
{
this.transformation = transformation;
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.z = z;
}

public String getTransformation() {
return transformation;
}

public void setTransformation(String transformation) {
this.transformation = transformation;
}

public String getX() {
return x;
}

public void setX(String x) {
this.x = x;
}

public String getY() {
return y;
}

public void setY(String y) {
this.y = y;
}

public String getZ() {
return z;
}

public void setZ(String z) {
this.z = z;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
return "TestBestMatchModel{" + "transformation='" + transformation + '\'' + ", 
x='" + x + '\''
    + ", y='" + y + '\'' + ", z='" + z + '\'' + '}';
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
if (this == o)
  return true;
if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
  return false;
TestBestMatchModel that = (TestBestMatchModel) o;
return Objects.equals(transformation, that.transformation) && 
Objects.equals(x, that.x)
    && Objects.equals(y, that.y) && Objects.equals(z, that.z);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {

return Objects.hash(transformation, x, y, z);
}
}
```